# How to use custom filter for yii2 ListView widget?

Tags: php, yii2

In my controller I rendered $dataProvider

```
$searchModel = new StudentSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

Here is search function of StudentSearch

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Student::find();

       $query->andFilterWhere([
        'student_id' => $this->student_id,
        'age' => $this->age,

    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'firstname', $this->firstname]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);


    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

in view I used  $dataprivider in  ListView widget like below

```
  <div class="listView">

   <?php
    echo ListView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_student_list',
    ]);
    ?>

  </div>
```

In   '_student_list.php' I listed students

my filters

```
  <div class="listFilter">
   <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
   <input type="text" name="age"/>
 </div>
```

Now I want filter Students by firstname or age. How can I do this? If you have any solution to this problem please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code of `StudentSearch` model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** Add filter form to your view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="student-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['method' => 'get']); ?>

    <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'firstname') ?>

    <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'age') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Apply', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

**2)** Prepare `StundentSearch` model to return `dataProvider` depending on received `GET` parameters.

These attributes must be specified in rules in order to massively assign them.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['firstname', 'string'],
        ['age', 'integer'],
    ];
}

public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

public function search($params)
{
    $query = Student::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['age' => $this->age])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'firstname', $this->firstname]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer, just change it to `$searchModel` since it's the used model.

Comment: It listed all result. Maybe we forgot something?

Comment: The code looks OK for me. Did you add attributes to the `rules()`?

Comment: Yes maybe problem in controller in Yii::$app->request->queryParams. Is there other way to request params?

Comment: What's wrong with it? `echo` something right before this line `$query->andFilterWhere(['age' => $this->age])` and then `exit()`. Then submit the form and see the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71387/discussion-between-guwanch-and-arogachev).

Comment: The problem is in the ActiveForm, it sends POST data while the SearchModel expects GET data on this line:

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

Comment: Add parameter to your ActiveForm:
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['method' => 'get']); ?>

Comment: @leealex Thanks for your remark, updated the answer. You can suggest edit too and it will be applied after moderation.

Comment: @arogachev Спасибо, так и сделаю в следующий раз :)